# How to change the text color of rightBarButtonItem Item in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to change the text color of the rightBarButtonItem item text and it blue by default . I am trying to change it to black .

My current code for that is:

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black

This does not change anything and the text color is the same . Added the cancel rightBarButtonItem image that i need to change the text from blue to black. How can i do that [image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code showing how you create the `UIBarButtonItem` for the Cancel button along with the attempt to set the `tineColor` so it can all be seen in context. Also point out if you are doing anything with the nav bar appearance.

Comment: This is the code i used to create:      let dismiss = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

Comment: Please put all relevant details in your question where it's easier to read and find.

Comment: I added how i created .

Comment: You need to put the code in the question, not in a comment. And you need to show all of the relevant code in context. One line here and one line there doesn't provide enough information about what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to initialize your `rightBarButtonItem` before setting its tint color otherwise your optional biding will fail silently:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = .init(
        barButtonSystemItem: .cancel,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(cancelAction)
    )
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black
}

@objc func cancelAction(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
   print(#function)
}
```

Comment: check my last edit

Comment: Why would you need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` when trying to update the appearance of a UIBarButtonItem? Also, this answer affects the whole nav bar, not just the one button (which may be fine for the OP or not).

Comment: FYI - I've just confirmed that simply doing `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black` (as the OP had it originally) works just fine - as long as the `rightBarButtonItem` has been set first. There's no need to set the whole nav bar. There's no need to do it in `viewWillAppear`, and there's no need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`.

Comment: @HangarRash I do know that it is not always required but I am pretty sure you should call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`when changing the navigation bar settings

Comment: @HangarRash I will update the post to only change the button's tint color

Comment: @LeoDabus `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` is only needed when you change a property on the view controller that affects the status bar such as `prefersStatusBarHidden` or `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

Comment: @HangarRash Updated the post as I agree with you that op was probably trying to set its tint color while the button was still nil.

Answer (score 1):

first make a outlet of Bar button item if using storyboard like

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuBtn:UIBarButtonItem!
```

at `ViewDidLoad()` function write this code which will change the tint colour of bar button aka text colour

```
self.menuBtn.tintColor = .red
```

This will chnage the tint colour of text.

if using programatically then you can do this. first embead the view controller in navigation controller. and at the `viewDidLoad()` function. you can code this.

```
@overide func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "editor", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(someAction(_ :)))
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .green
}
```

This will change the tint colour of the bar button item into green

Comment: This assumes OP is using a storyboard

Comment: @Abhishek The OP stated (in the comments below the question) that the button is created via code, not in a storyboard. There's no need to create an outlet if it is created via code.

Comment: yes, thank you for informing i have edited the comment and also added how to change the colour using programmatically